# Dapper QueryAsync with two params

Tags: dapper

I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID AND VALUE = @VALUE";

var listTest = await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Example>(sql, ID, VALUE);
```

I want to query a table with a Composite PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
var listTest = await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Example>(sql, new { ID, VALUE });
```